# Append method to add text to body not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is such a simple command and I am loading jQuery beforehand. Other jQuery on the page is working as well. But this `append()` code won't work:-

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("test");
});
```

I have put this code in footer, right before the `</body>` close tag.

Comment: Actually I had script tags there in my code, that wasn't the issue, but when I removed some commented out code from above this code, it worked. Strange. :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("test");
});
  </script>
```

Add script tag before $(document).ready
visit https://w3codegenerator.com/code-snippets/jquery/append-method-to-add-text-to-body-not-working

Comment: Actually I had script tags there in my code, that wasn't the issue, but when I removed some commented out code from above this code, it worked. Strange. But thanks for your input anyways. :)